# HTTP Status 404 Spring MVC Passing Parameters

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, servlets, spring-mvc

I want to start work with Spring MVC, but can not adjust a simple example. I want to just pass one parameter form one jsp to another, but have error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /controller/results.jsp type Status report message
>   /controller/results.jsp description The requested resource
>   (/controller/results.jsp) is not available. Apache Tomcat/7.0.12

My web.xml code:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.demidov.controller" />

</beans:beans>
```

Controller.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4825408935018763217L;  

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);      

    EducationDaoInterface educationDaoIntfc;

    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView  firstActionPage() {    

        return new ModelAndView("home");

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/result.jsp", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String SecondActionPage(@RequestParam String firstname, Model model) throws IOException {

        model.addAttribute("myname", firstname);

        return "result";

    }
```

Result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

Hello form result.jsp

First name: ${myname}

</body>
</html>
```

Home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" action="<c:url value="/results.jsp"/>" method="GET">

<input type="text"  name="firstname"/>

<input type="submit"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: try to cahange mapping on <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>, In your case after submit url not handled with spring mvc and you get error

Comment: Thank you so much Georgy for help. Right, When I change it it seems like it's work. Just  I got confused what is url-pattern for.. I thought by default it's map my request when I do Run on Server and it's suppouse to use this url-pattern to direct me to my first RequestMapping method. But how can I do action between two pages using form. what I do is put http://localhost:8080/controller/result?firstname=hello and it's goes to my jsp but I want to use action from one page to another.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong URL mapping.

There are two solutions.

1.

You can change the url mapping of SecondActionPage function in your controller to following.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

And also change the form action in Home.jsp to `<c:url value="/results"/>`

2.

You can change the url-pattern of your appServlet to `/*`. That is the standard way to url-pattern in Spring web application.
And then you need to change the request mapping and action in home.jsp as I have suggested in solution 1.

I recommend you solution 2. That is best practice.

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Japs for you help.. I did not understand the second solution. I thought my url-pattern /* is just goes to my /* as default when I do Run on Server, but it's also doesn't work.. Please could you explane me in more details or point me on good documentation to read. Thank you Japs.

Comment: as per my second solution you need to change the url-pattern to `/*` and then change the request mapping to `/result`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>




@RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView  firstActionPage() {    
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String SecondActionPage(@RequestParam String firstname, Model model) throws IOException {
    model.addAttribute("myname", firstname);
    return "result";
}

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
<body>

    <form name="myform" action="/result" method="GET">
        <input type="text"  name="firstname"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeha Georgy. I already tried this. It seems like it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to provide complete name of jsp file with extension as it will handled by `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`.

Change your form action to :

`<form name="myform" action="result" method="GET">  //check spelling and remove '/' from url`

And controller mapping to :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you Naresh. But It's still not working... Maybe something wrong with my tomcat I already tried everything. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have got this after all of the tying when I click on submit button from my home jsp to another controller url is:

```
 `http://localhost:8080/controller/result?firstname=Vadim
```

it seems like I passing everything corectly to my controller but why my result.jsp page doesn't not appears

> HTTP Status 404 - /controller/result
>
> type Status report
>
> message /controller/result
>
> description The requested resource (/controller/result) is not
>   available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.12

Comment: what is controller in your path? Applciation context path?

Comment: Georgy Thank you for you help. I solve the problem. I put in my web.xml <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> and rename my home.jsp now it appears on start up. After I click submit button, it's transfer me on my result.jsp with my parameters, but problem is that I put in my form action in index.jsp this: /controller/result and I don't know why, but if I have just like this: /result after submit it direct me to: http://localhost:8080/result?firstname=abc and I can't reach result.jsp, besides my <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> it's seems like doesn't work anymore I change it but nothing happend.